# Работа с аудио-устройствами .NET

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Захотелось поработать со звуком - хочу взять какой-нибудь аудиофайл и воспроизвести его не на устройстве установленном по умолчанию, а например подать поток в микрофон.

Существуют ли какие-нибудь библиотеки, позволяющие провернуть подобное?
Можете ли посоветовать какую-нибудь литературу для изучения данного вопроса?

Искал в интернете, но ни на что более универсального SoundPlayer не наткнулся.

P.S. прошу прощения, если информация по данному вопросу на самом деле легкодоступна и я сам плохо искал.

Comment: В наше время драйвер микрофона технически не может воспроизводить звуки, так как это может вывести из строя устройство.

Comment: да, я знаю, я имею в виду чтобы звук шел в канал, прослушиваемый другими приложениями как устройство ввода

Comment: Можно использовать NAudio, а там по документации найдёте где менять вывод аудиопотока